# Spring Boot, using same endpoint to call 2 functions (optional params)

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, controller, get

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a single endpoint of `/api/test` with the following criteria.

There are 3 optional parameters, `foo, bar & dove`

I need two responses based on combinations of these.

E.g.

```
/api/test?foo=foo&bar=bar (calls function to return ObjectA)


/api/test?foo=foo&dove=dove (calls function to return ObjectB)
```

This would work if I had unique parameters for each url, but they both share `foo`. How can I map them separately even if they share an optional param?

Here is what I tried:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
.
.
.
@GetMapping(params={"bar"})
public List<ObjectA> getAllObjectA(@RequestParam("bar") String bar,
                                   @RequestParam("foo") Optional<String> foo){

    return service.getAllObjectA(bar, foo.orElse("");
}

@GetMapping(params={"dove"})
public List<ObjectB> getAllObjectB(@RequestParam("dove") String dove,
                                   @RequestParam("foo") Optional<String> foo){

    return service.getAllObjectB(dove, foo.orElse(""));
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: dose `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` has any common attributes ? can you share the code ?

Comment: @Deadpool, they have a common attribute of foo

Answer (score 3):

You can change your code to return `ResponseEntity<?>`

```
 if (some condition) {
    return new ResponseEntity<List<ObjectA>>(service.getAllObjectA(bar, foo.orElse(""), HttpStatus.OK);
} else if (...) {
    return new ResponseEntity<List<ObjectB>>(service.getAllObjectB(dove, foo.orElse(""), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about ResponseEntity. That looks promising!